# How many indexes can we create on a SQL Server table according to the SQL Server versions?

Tags: sql-server

How many many indexes can we create on one table in each of the SQL Server versions, including clustered and nonclustered indexes.

Answer (score 3):

According to the "Maximum Capacity Specification" page for SQL Server, you can have **exactly ONE** clustered index, and **up to 999** nonclustered indices per table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

This is valid for versions back to SQL Server 2014 (can't find anything for older versions - you should not use those anymore, any way!), and for both 32- and 64-bit versions, and does not seem to change from edition to edition (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise).

But I agree with @scsimon - if you get *even remotely* close to that limit - there's a **huge** design smell in your solution! Something is very bad if you even approach that many indices on a single table ....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the maximum number of [indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017) a table can have, you should probably change your thought process. You should never hit this limit (if there even is one), and probably should take some [advice from some performance gurus.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/index-tuning-week-how-many-indexes-are-too-many/)

One *question* that can be answered that you asked is how many clustered indexes can be created on a table. The answer is **one** per table. A clustered index defines the order in which the data is *physically* stored on disk... which can only be one way.